# jquery iframe onload for iframe

Tags: jquery, onload

I am loading in an iframe from RightMove and I want to remove certain aspects of it.  I've tried CSS and jQuery but I think the onLoad is not working.  Here is my code:

```
jQuery('#advanced_iframe_2').load(function() { 
    jQuery("#globalHeader").hide();
    console.log('Working status 1');
});
```

And I am trying this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#advanced_iframe_2').ready(function() {
   console.log('Working status 2');
  });
});
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Cheers

Comment: Not sure will read through. Cheers

Comment: It is not possible to modify the contents of a third-party iframe.  That link isn't a duplicate, as it describes how to trigger a function *in the parent window* when the iframe loads; you want to trigger a function in the iframe, which would require cooperation (at least CORS access) from the framed site.

Comment: Unless you can edit the other site (*RightMove*?) you can't detect when the iframe is fully loaded. In those cases you can try `window.onload` which is the last phase of page load. You can only access the `<iframe>` but nothing inside of it.

Comment: You cannot modify the content of a cross-domain iframe unless the third-party has explicitly allowed it, which is *extremely* unlikely for a public-facing website.

Comment: Thanks to all who have commented. Ah bugger..